# List, strings and vs Template

Tags: c#, string, list, templates

I'm having a list of strings whit some values and I want to make some kind of variable for keeping code that I will be using in template file.

For example lets say I have list with this 3 string values: configService, scaleCoefConfigService, sessionService. Name of the list is chItemName.

And I need to generate this kind of code that I will parse later into template:

```
[Dependency("configService")]

[Dependency("scaleCoefConfigService")]

[Dependency("sessionService")]
```

So my question is can make some variable and mechanism for iterating thou list of strings that adds every single item from list to variable?

I've tried this:

```
foreach (var tp in controllerChecked)
{
   var genCode = "[Dependency](" '"'  + chItemName + '"'")] \n"
}
```

controllerChecked is collection of objects and one of the objects value is Name that I'm getting like this:

```
var chItemName = controllerChecked.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

This is how the list chItemName is getting those strings.

But of course it is impossible to use + with lists and this kind of stuff will never work. Someone has better idea?

Comment: You're not using `tp`, but `chItemName`. Did you rename one and not the other? Where does `chItemName` come from?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis oh you are right, forgot one important part of code that explains what is chItemName I will add it right away in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are not using the `tp` variable, which contains will contain each of the values within `controllerChecked`, one at a time.

You could just iterate through the `chItemName` list and add the result to a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder codeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string tp in chItemName)
{
    codeBuilder.AppendLine("[Dependency(\"" + tp + "\")]");
}

string code = codeBuilder.ToString();
```

If `controllerChecked` contains more information, you could also directly access it:

```
StringBuilder codeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in controllerChecked)
{
    string propertyName = item.Name.SubString(1);

    codeBuilder.AppendLine("[Dependency(\"" + item.Name + "\")]");
    codeBuilder.AppendLine("public " + item.Type + " " + propertyName + " { get; set; }");
    codeBuilder.AppendLine();
}

string code = codeBuilder.ToString();
```

PS. I would definitely change the name of `chItemName` to `chItemNames` as it is a list, but that is up to you of course.

Comment: Yes controllerChecked is the list, but not that kind of list. It's a list of objects. So basically I need to put chItemName that is list of strings in that foreach.
Thanks for responding, I will try it right away.

Comment: It worked :D I have one more question if you maybe know the answer. What if I'm using 3 different lists? I will write new post or update first one to explain you what I'm thinking. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly good. I have little bit harder version of this, if you can figure out how to do this:

Lets say that instead of one chItemName list I have 2 more: fName and chItemType, both are string lists.

And I have to generate this kind of code:

```
[Dependency("alarmsService")]
public IAlarmsService AlarmsService { get; set; }

[Dependency("jsonFactory")]
public IJSONFactoryService JsonFactory { get; set; }

[Dependency("dataBean")]
public IDataBean DataBean { get; set; }
```

alarmsServise, jsonFactory and dataBean are items of chItemName.
IAlarmsService, IJSONFactoryService and IDataBean are items of chItemType.
AlarmsService, Json Factory and DataBean are items of fName list.

fName is list that I got from chItemType by trimming the first letter from each string in list:

```
List<string> fName = new List<string>();
foreach(var i in chItemType)
{
    var newName = i.Remove(0,1);
    fName.Add(newName);
}
```

So only that list is not a part of controllerChecked list. The othere two are defined like this:

```
var chItemType = controllerChecked.Select(c => c.Type).ToList();
var chItemName = controllerChecked.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Can I edit foreach somehow or maybe I can make parts of code with StringBulider and after that merged them together?

Comment: Is all data available in `controllerChecked`? IE. we already covered the `Name` property, are the other values also properties of each element in `controllerChecked`? (already updated my answer to accomodate that)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis well two are Type and Name, but last one fName is not. fName is actually list of substrings from Type. I will update my post so you can see it. :)

Comment: I'm off for lunch :P See if you can fix things with my updated answer. You should be able to put your substring logic inside that foreach.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis ok I will do my best. Thanks for new answer and enjoy your lunch. :)